# Passing many props inside dispatch with Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

With Redux, when passing state and dispatch from a component via connect, there is a need to use some state values inside dispatch when clicking a button (that is generated by map).

I bypassed a value inside my button tag with value, but it doesn't seem like the smart way to do it and it allows only one state. Any conceptual mistake here?

```js
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { manageGold, addEnhancement } from '../actions/actions'

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        enhancements: state[0].enhancements
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {   
        manageBuyEnhancement: (event) => {
            dispatch(addEnhancement(/* Pass Enhancement Here */))   
            dispatch(manageGold(event.target.value))        
        }
    }
}

function Enhancements(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <h4>Enhancements</h4>
            {props.enhancements.map(enh =>
                <div key={Math.random()}>
                    <p>{enh.enhancementName}</p>
                    <p>Price: {enh.enhancementPrice}</p>
                    <p>Qty: {enh.enhancementQty}</p>
                    <button onClick={props.manageBuyEnhancement} value={enh.enhancementName}>Buy!</button>
                </div>

                )
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps, 
    mapDispatchToProps,
    null,
    {
        pure: false
    }
)(Enhancements)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add as many arguments as you want. You can use for that function or higher order function.

```
manageBuyEnhancement: (event, enhancement)=>{
  dispatch(addEnhancement(enhancement))   
  dispatch(manageGold(event.target.value))
}

...

<button onClick={event=>props.manageBuyEnhancement(event,enhancement)} value={enh.enhancementName}>Buy</button>
```

or

```
manageBuyEnhancement: enhancement => event =>{
  dispatch(addEnhancement(enhancement))   
  dispatch(manageGold(event.target.value))
}
...
 <button onClick={props.manageBuyEnhancement(enhancement)} value={enh.enhancementName}>Buy</button>
```